# How can light speed be measured relatively?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, inertial-frames, faster-than-light

Following scenario:

Two rockets leave a planet, heading opposite direction.
Assuming the rockets are capable of accelariting highly - when would there be a barrier?
Einstein said, nothing can be faster than light. But if both rockets flew with c/2 relatively to the planet, wouldn't they fly with c relatively to each other (which is not possible)?

Time is said to be faster for a moving object, but how is it determined whether an object is moved or not? I mean, there is no absolute place this can be measured from...

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that lengths and time intervals transform when you move to a different reference frame, so do velocities. So, in your scenario, an observer on Earth would measure each rocket as having a speed of $\frac{c}{2}$. However, the speed at which one rocket would perceive the other would be different than just $\frac{c}{2} + \frac{c}{2}$, since you have to do the transformation to that rocket's reference frame. The details of how to do so are [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Transformation_of_velocities).